# Clearing App Data on update

Tags: android, version-control, versioning, android-version

I need to clear(equivalent to **Clear Data** in **App Settings**) all the old data in the app programmatically when the user **updates** the app from Google Play Store or any other sources. This is because I don't need any of the existing data from the old app since I have changed everything in the new app compared to the old one.

I thought of implementing a version check at the app startup, but I can't find a way to get the app's **previous** `versionCode` or `versionName`. The only way I figured out to clear the data is to check the `lastUpdateTime` at the time of publishing the app. But it's not reliable since the user has other ways or sources of getting the app (like sharing it with a friend or if the user had a backup of the old app).

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I want to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @kash I did not try any of the suggestions below since I was working in other things. But I believe atleast one of the solutions below will work

Answer (score 9):

You can store `versionCode` in `SharedPreferences` and compare with current `versionCode`

For clear all data you just need to clear all value of SharedPreferences, Local Database and all local files which you have store.

```
public void clearData()
    {
        try {
            PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            int mCurrentVersion = pInfo.versionCode;
            SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("app_name",  Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            mEditor.apply();
            int last_version = mSharedPreferences.getInt("last_version", -1);
            if(last_version != mCurrentVersion)
            {
                //clear all your data like database, share preference, local file 
                //Note : Don't delete last_version value in share preference
            }
            mEditor.putInt("last_version", mCurrentVersion);
            mEditor.commit();
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Note** : Don't delete **last_version** value in share preference.

Comment: Your answer will work only if I had saved the version in Shared Preferences in the old app. Unfortunately I have not saved the version in any of the storages.

Comment: @Joshua still you can do, if value is null then you can clear all your data.

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori just need to change that condition.

Comment: Yes i messed it up, `if(mSharedPreferences.getInt("last_version", -1) != mCurrentVersion)` should do it

Comment: @Joshua check my updated answer, it will also work for old app

Comment: @Joshua [if found solution then you can accept right answer so it will help to other user in future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Niranj ya sure. I still didn't test it out. I had some other features to be done. Once I test it and get it right, I'll surely update the status.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use a `PACKAGE_REPLACED` receiver which gets fired whenever a package is replaced in your phone (also happens when updating an app). Declare it in your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".UpdateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        <data android:scheme="package" android:path="com.my.app"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And add your receiver class. `onReceive` will get called when the app is updated:

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context con, Intent intent) {
        
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** you don't need to filter the package. Use `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` instead which will fire only for your app.

Comment: Will the receiver get registered as soon as the update is installed? Because I assume that it will be registered when the user opens the app atleast once(since the previous app doesn't have this receiver).

Comment: hi Drilon, where receiver class should be added? MainActivity.java ?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to a system broadcast with following intent and filter in onReceive with your package name to see if your app is updated.

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
   <data android:scheme="package" />
</intent-filter>
```