# Clearing app data and cache when releasing new update

Tags: android

I am releasing a new update, that will change my app build completely from the last version. I want the the app to be fresh and delete all old unceccery cache and data for current users.
How can I achieve this? what the right code to use, and where to add it exactly, I am not expert in android development, so please guide me more specifically. I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520051/clearing-app-data-on-update), but there's no mention of what code actually works to clear data and cache.

My setup (incase needed):

```
// Android Studio 3.0        
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3' (Gradle)
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to my MainActivity is what worked for me to clear cache and data.

```
   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      try {
         trimCache(this);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static void trimCache(Context context) {
      try {
         File dir = context.getCacheDir();
         if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDir(dir);
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO: handle exception
      }
   }

   public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
      if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
         String[] children = dir.list();
         for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
               return false;
            }
         }
      }

      // The directory is now empty so delete it
      return dir.delete();
   }

}
```

Answer found here: [Clear Application cache on exit in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10977373/2976631).

> Now cache is cleared every time, a user closes the app, it works for
>   me since I don't want to keep cache from webview, for others who
>   want to clear this on updates only, implementing this with onReceive
>   should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to event in a bordcast receiver class, when your application is updated & do the cleanup in onReceive of your broadcast receiver.

The following comment in the link you shared :) has all the details.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48520332/8312634

Comment: Will it work even if I didn't declare a reciver in my previous version? And whats the proper method to clear data and cache? That's my biggest concern.

Comment: I believe you'll get this event after the application is updated, not before. So you can have the cleaup code executed on that event. Also, what do you mean by data & cache? If its a file, you'll need to delete them, or if its something like sharedprefs, you can clear them like so https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear()

Comment: The old version uses Webview the cache and data are related to the Webview.

Comment: Try this to clear cache of WebView: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#clearCache%28boolean%29